# Python script to automate search form a website?

Tags: python

I was able to use this below to automate opening a website for example here if I use youtube, is there a way I can put it

I'm trying to find a way to automate search "fishing" into this code but struggling to find the best way to do it.

Any recommendations would greatly appreciated

```
import webbrowser

new=2;
url="http://youtube.com"
webbrowser.open(url,new=new);
```

or way to go about it ?

Comment: The `webbrowser` module doesn't seem to be very full-featured, I would would look into [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) for general browser-based web usage

Comment: @G.Anderson I will thank you so much that's such a great help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a get request, passing the search query parameters to this link.

*https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=**fishing***